# Is there a way to save volume setting for each video on YouTube?

Tags: audio, video, youtube

Let's say I have a playlist, storing some classical music videos from different channels. The problem is that some music videos are louder and some are softer, so I need to tune the volume from video to video.

As the list will be replay many times, is there a way I can save the volume settings for each video so that I don't need to tune every time?

Comment: Do the videos play in a web browser and which one if so?

Comment: @McDonald's I usually use Chrome to connect to Youtube website, but I am open to any option as long as I am using Youtube.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, no. YouTube volume is stored as a single value in a cookie for the entire site. The only option really is to obtain the audio files yourself and change the volume.

There may be some kind of software solution out there, kind of like what Windows Volume Mixer is but that could adjust the volumes automatically, but I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: Sounds like it is something that can be solved by using an extension?

Comment: @cytsunny That's a brilliant idea. Although I couldn't find an extension on the Chrome store to do that, I'd imagine something can be built either with the video URL or the video ID.

Comment: If nothing else is possible, tampermonkey script might do the trick. (wow this question is 6 years old!)